# how to find google spreadsheet duplicates and remove only from one column data

Tags: google-sheets, filter, formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have spreadsheet columns,  `A, B, C`

I wanna compare **A and B** column and remove duplicates from only **B** Column (Ex: If any data already exist in column A I wanna remove that from Column B)

Finally I wanna extract that data to a new column

please check the attachment

[image: sample attachment]

---

```
| A        | B         |
|----------|-----------|
| mango    | banana    |
| banana   | avecado   |
| avecado  | apple     |
| apple    | carambola |
| grapes   | cherry    |
| guvava   | mandarine |
| lemon    |           |
| apricots |           |
```

Comment: only for google spreadsheet

Comment: thank you so much for your help it's working now <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `C1`, try:

```
=FILTER(B1:B,COUNTIF(A1:A,B1:B)=0)
```

Comment: Sir, previously I wrote the `query` incorrectly as the answer. Check it now. However, your solution is far better and shorter. :)

Comment: @Madhurjya, yes I saw it, and quickly realised it wasn't correct. I'll credit you for the correct answer trhough `QUERY` again as it's a fascinating function I need to familiarize myself with a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in `C1`:

`=QUERY(A1:B8,"select B where not B matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",true,A1:A8)& " ' ")`

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]